# Error after Deleting Unused Categories that came with theme

Tags: magento2

I was deleting the categories that came with a theme I purchased for Magento 2, and adding in my own, but now when I visit the site I get this error:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with id = 233
```

Comment: try to remove deleted category from products and reindex.

Comment: It may be due to some of products are still having that same category which you have deleted.

Comment: The products are all new products I created and I didn't select categories for them

Comment: I have the same issue and already tried to reindex. But still get an error. Any help?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/128131)

Answer (score 1):

My store had a reference to a deleted category in the catalog_category_product_index table. The following SQL solved the issue.

```
DELETE FROM catalog_category_product_index WHERE category_id = 233;
```

(substitute the ID from your error at the end)

Comment: Unfortunately I decided to start from scratch, so I'm unable to verify if this would have been a fix, but hopefully somebody else will come across this and it can help them. Sounds like a possible solution